# How to sum numbers in parenthesis within a cell until a certain condition is met?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Here's the problem, I got a cell, say,

> WH,QC-NDE(**0.75**),CHL150-1(**5.05**),HMCT12P1(1),B-S(0.2),QC-NDE(0.5),TIGPEC05(17.25),SR,CHL150-1(23),HMCT12P1(42),B-S(1.5),QC,QC-H(0.35),QC-NDE(0.75),INSP_FIN(1)

I would like to add all the numbers in brackets (parenthesis) from left to right until it reaches the first CHL150-1.

And if there is the word "SR" in front of CHL150-1, add 72.

So for the above example, the value returned will be 0.75 + 5.05 = 5.80 as shown in bold.

> TIGPEC05(**17.25**),**SR**,CHL150-1(**23**),HMCT12P1(42),B-S(1.5),QC,QC-H(0.35),QC-NDE(0.75),INSP_FIN(1)
>
> The value returned above will be 17.25 + 72 + 23 = 112.25 instead.

And ideally, the choice of what condition to trigger the end can be modified.
(eg. change CHL150-1 to HMCT12P1)

Would appreciate any kind help. Prefer formula and UDF or a mixture of both. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```vba
Public Function mysum(source As String, delim As String) As Double
source = "," & source & ","
delim = "," & delim & "("
If InStr(source, delim) > 0 Then
    source = Left(source, InStr(1 + InStr(source, delim), source, ","))
End If
If InStr(source, ",SR,") > 0 Then
    mysum = 72
End If
Do Until InStr(source, "(") = 0
    source = Mid(source, 1 + InStr(source, "("))
    mysum = mysum + Val(source)
    source = Mid(source, InStr(source, ")"))
Loop
End Function
```

where

- *source* - data cell (containing "WH,QC-NDE(0.75), ... ,INSP_FIN(1)")
- *delim* - delimiter-terminator ("CHL150-1", "HMCT12P1", ...)

Both parameters can be both cell addresss and literal.

"SR" and 72 can be converted from hardcoded constants to (optional) parameters too.

If you want to rename the function you must replace ALL occurences of it in the code (4 times).

[image: How to use]

Comment: Akina,  How to use this Function ? Put some example in answer !!

Comment: Open VBA editor (Alt-F11). Insert - Module. Insert the above code into. Close VBA Editor. Now you can use this function in this wirkbook as a common built-in one. It can be found in "User-defined functions" in a formula master or in full list of functions by alphabet.

Comment: [Create custom functions in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f)

Comment: Akina,, I'm well versed with Programming /VBA  & others and I know how to create code. My question was how to use the UDF in terms of a Formula? Like your  UDF =mysum(range) or what ??

Comment: For example `C1 = mysum(A1, B1)` where A1 contains your long string and B1 contains the "terminator" you want to use. Or `C1 = mysum(A1, "CHL150-1")` if you want to use static terminator value.

Comment: @RajeshS "How to use" screenshot added. Or see the "Making your custom functions available anywhere" section (1st part of it) by the link given above.

Comment: OP is looking for `17.25 + 72 + 23` = `112.25`  and the function returns `0.75` !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83155/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-akina).

Comment: @RajeshS Code restored, screenshot replaced.

Comment: @Akina Wow this works flawlessly! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This method uses the `Split` function

```
Option Explicit
Function SumSpecial(str As String) As Double
    Dim V, W
    Dim I As Long
    Dim D As Double
    Const strEnd As String = "CHL150-1"
    Const str72 As String = "SR"

V = Split(str, ",")

I = 0
Do
    W = Split(V(I), "(")
    If UBound(W) = 1 Then
        D = D + Val(W(1))
    End If
    If W(0) = str72 And _
        Split(V(I + 1), "(")(0) = strEnd Then
        D = D + 72
    End If
    I = I + 1
Loop Until W(0) = strEnd

SumSpecial = D

End Function
```

Comment: This works fine too, but what can be improved is that: 

Const strEnd As String = "CHL150-1"

needs to be re-edited in the event that there is a change in parameter (eg. to CHL152-1 instead). But it works well enough too! Appreciate your kind contributions! =]

Comment: @hahafwkit Just change that variable from a defined constant within the function, to an argument (or an `Optional` argument) within the function call. Since you did not specify that item would be variable in your original question, it was not coded as such, but to change it is trivial.